# Dynamically add and remove a User Control from a Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Web User Control that I need to add to a page simply in order to add it to an `HtmlForm` so I can send an email with this User Control, however, I do not need this Control to appear on the page, I just need it to fill with data so I can send this email, and then be removed so it does not appear on the page.

Currently I have tried:

```
myControl c = new myControl();
c.InitializeAsUserControl(Page);
c.fillInfo(data);

//add to email form and send email
```

yet this adds the control to the current page on post back once the email has been sent and a confirmation message

I have also tried

```
myControl c = (myControl)Page.LoadControl("~/filename.ascx");
//send email
Page.Controls.Remove(c);
```

yet this also renders the control on the page and does not remove it.  I have tried to add it to a panel and set Visible to false, but unfortunately this does not work either. If I simply create a `new myControl()` without rendering on page or calling `LoadControl` I get exceptions thrown when `fillInfo` is called when it tries to modify `asp:labels` in the User Control saying that the objects are null or not instantiated.

Comment: It's not clear how the control gets attached to the page in your first example, instantiating a control does not explicitly add it to the page.

Comment: @MyItchyChin I updated my first example to make it more clear

Comment: Ah, that's where it's getting bound.  Does the usercontrol need anything off the page?  If not you can instantiate an instance of a page and pass that in instead.

Comment: @MyItchyChin I tried to instantiate another page, and while nothing excepts,  the email does not have my user control

Answer (score 1):

Which part of the page cycle are you loading and unloading the controls? To work properly it needs to be done in `Page_Init`. It's a common mistake to do it in `Page_Load`. If it is added anywhere else other than `Page_Init` it won't be added to the `ViewState` correctly and problems will ensue.

Rather than unload - I would add it to a Panel and set Visibility to false. Could be the reason that isn't working for you at the moment is that the control is being added at the wrong part of the page cycle and isn't being added to `ViewState` correctly.

Could that be your problem?

Comment: All this happens on a form submission so it's a separate event. As you can see in the question, I have tried to add it to a Panel as set Visible=false yet that does not seem to work either...

Comment: @avivas. Then unfortunately it's too late in the cycle. Page_Init has passed - dynamic controls won't work.  I honestly try to avoid them because they are so difficult to work with. Is it not possible to have ghe control on the page but hidden - does it need to be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the entire [TRULY UNDERSTANDING DYNAMIC CONTROLS](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx) series. To successfully use dynamic controls with postbacks, viewstate, bindings, and the other WebForms *features*, you really have to know the page and control lifecycles and their interactions inside out.

When you load and set ViewState depends on the cycle. ViewState is loaded between Page_Init and Page_Load, so the control has to be in Page_Init. However, any processing based on auto-loaded ViewState, needs to go in Page_Load. Where/when ViewState is enabled depending on the control hierarchy can also affect this. I suggest you read that guide above in depth if you really want it to work. Or, you'll have to post your entire control code and its use in a page for us to tell you which parts you are missing or have in the wrong part of the page lifecycle.

I've made dynamic controls work, but 99% of the time, unless the control is extremely trivial, it's easier to find a different solution than it is to make sure all the interactions work correctly with dynamic control creation.

Comment: Thanks for your input I will look at the series but at the time I will most likely try to find a different solution